# How to use the json output from aws Amazon Transcribe Medical

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, speech-to-text

the output is made of json with the whole text and each speaker segments like so:

```
"speaker_labels": {
      "speakers": 2,
      "segments": [
        {
          "start_time": "0.94",
          "speaker_label": "spk_0",
          "end_time": "3.065",
          "items": [
            {
              "start_time": "1.01",
              "speaker_label": "spk_0",
              "end_time": "1.22"
            },
.
.
.
```

and then the each word and its timestamp

```
    "items": [
      {
        "start_time": "1.01",
        "end_time": "1.22",
        "alternatives": [{ "confidence": "1.0", "content": "word" }],
        "type": "pronunciation"
      },
      {
        "start_time": "1.22",
        "end_time": "1.81",
        "alternatives": [{ "confidence": "1.0", "content": "word" }],
        "type": "pronunciation"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [{ "confidence": "0.0", "content": "another word" }],
        "type": "punctuation"
      },
.
.
.
```

and i need each speaker's words how am i suppose to get that data without doing alot of logic with the start end time of the words and all the start end of the speakers.
the result i expect:

```
spk_0 : words words words
spk_1 : words words more words
```

Comment: Ever find a suitable solution for this @Gabi Rousine